# How to get country code using Smart IP Module?

Tags: 7

How do I get the country code of the current visitor of the site and just simply display it in a block?
I am using [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module. I tried following the instructions from the module's page but I think it only points to the IP of the server.
Here is my code:

```
    $smart_ip_session = smart_ip_session_get('smart_ip');
    if ($smart_ip_session['location']['country_code'] == 'PH') {
      drupal_set_message(t('You are in the Philippines.'), 'status');
    } else {
    drupal_set_message(t('You are in ' . $smart_ip_session['location']['country_code']), 'status');
}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct; did you try installing the [Session Cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_cache) module and fetching the info that way? Maintainers recommend that way actually.

Comment: Yes sir. I already installed Session Cache API. The country code displays as 'US', where in fact I'm not from US. I think it returns the country code of the web server.

Comment: Very strange; just checking: when you were using Session Cache module, did you use the other code example? If yes, and if it still didn't work, I would try this on a clean install to make sure nothing else interferes with this.

Comment: yes sir. I used the plain $_SESSION code. It still didn't work. Btw, I'm using Maxmind binary database lite version, as smart ip source. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/a843po
I've read that this is not that accurate. Does this affect it?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It could be; I suggest doing the following: 1) try this on a clean install; if the issue is still there, proceed to: 2) post this as an issue / support request in the [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/smart_ip?categories=All).

Answer (score 0):

Just set some value to "Frequency of user's geolocation checking", clear cache and that's it!

And if you're in a reverse proxy server, don't forget to insert the following in your site's settings.php

```
  // Tell Drupal that we are behind a reverse proxy server
  $conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;

  // List of trusted IPs (IP numbers of our reverse proxies)
  $conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array(
    '127.0.0.1',
  );
```